# GLM returning negative values for suitability in species distribution modeling

Tags: r, modeling, glm

I have started to work with species distribution modeling with GLM. Using BIOCLIM environmental data (for example: Bio10, Bio15, Bio16, Bio17 as `predictors`), the following data (stored in an object `presausTrain`):

```
      ID bioclim_10   bioclim_11 bioclim_15 bioclim_16 pres longitude latitude
2      2  225.00000 105.00000000  22.206624  299.18014    1  -58.8786 -34.2269
3      3  228.97882 112.97809077  27.000000  319.94470    1  -59.5144 -33.7806
4      4  219.00000 104.57779206  16.000000  265.57779    1  -57.2555 -35.2549
6      6  188.00000  83.00000000  18.000000  260.42379    1  -57.5419 -38.0551
9      9  224.58419 104.73418836  23.000000  320.08305    1  -58.9186 -34.4132
10    10  243.60300  94.16917531  64.561824   85.17573    1  -68.6146 -32.8886
11    11  224.58433 104.73658836  23.000000  320.09025    1  -58.9187 -34.4133
12    12  253.00000  97.00000000  68.608231   71.99121    1  -68.5041 -32.3345
13    13  224.60863 104.75578836  23.000000  320.02305    1  -58.9195 -34.4128
15    15  245.44112  94.58706179  64.849824   84.25853    1  -68.6026 -32.8416
16    16  264.02281 151.00000000  54.022813  393.34787    1  -60.7727 -28.6506
17    17  244.67617 128.19141384  48.323829  366.28249    1  -60.6717 -31.6380
18    18  263.00000 149.49003689  53.490037  391.42668    1  -60.7500 -28.7500
19    19  272.04463 181.06767992  43.272909  412.80043    1  -58.1522 -25.1102
20    20  250.00000 132.00000000  49.877386  358.92412    1  -60.8829 -31.2539
21    21  268.54597 165.00000000  32.000000  418.09660    1  -58.0293 -28.0340
26    26  263.03251 149.36775948  53.286986  392.57182    1  -60.7333 -28.7333
27    27  262.00000 149.00000000  52.954712  394.07047    1  -60.6666 -28.7857
28    28  194.26954  91.54652958 113.000000  221.44775    1  -70.8308 -33.2159
29    29  195.00139  91.98381950 113.000000  219.30565    1  -70.8255 -33.2179
30    30  194.71515  92.34394042 113.000000  219.32903    1  -70.8312 -33.1968
31    31  194.87274  92.25693323 113.000000  218.64974    1  -70.8271 -33.2033
32    32  262.51488 149.00000000  53.000000  391.44238    1  -60.7334 -28.7999
33    33  236.09116 148.19977261  21.050265  543.87328    1  -53.9738 -25.8564
34    34  244.17649 128.15908399  47.077874  363.03794    1  -60.6339 -31.6890
36    36  249.80369 132.80368760  47.196312  364.22593    1  -60.2472 -31.2462
37    37  268.00000 164.88563766  32.000000  414.86622    1  -58.0654 -28.0482
38    38  268.00000 164.86220565  32.000000  414.68268    1  -58.0699 -28.0454
39    39  256.00000 142.51301366  48.000000  358.57247    1  -60.5333 -29.7500
40    40  255.02037 143.12581264  46.732643  438.70468    1  -59.7161 -29.3281
41    41  264.00000 151.00000000  54.000000  394.65955    1  -60.7500 -28.6500
42    42  254.54615 164.95675375  19.200389  502.30639    1  -54.4563 -25.6887
43    43  272.00000 173.71328176  36.025171  467.51253    1  -58.1000 -26.5833
44    44  286.97773 208.08168096  56.000000  292.08590    1  -59.5522 -21.2787
45    45  224.22325  78.22324976  38.606279  185.39521    1  -63.5337 -37.7471
46    46  248.74987 159.74987480  27.453648  559.43635    1  -54.2713 -25.6734
47    47  209.41746 124.45790111 107.988728  331.33831    1  -71.6073 -33.5050
48    48  244.38027 128.36415875  49.000000  369.61503    1  -60.6817 -31.5992
49    49  162.85989  96.36235347 118.491117  443.99917    1  -71.5244 -33.1645
50    50  130.32560  17.41336935  68.079547  360.58826    1  -71.1000 -40.9500
51    51  139.05510  25.70054673  69.765255  389.11327    1  -71.0837 -40.9810
52    52  209.13482 124.35046642 107.868234  332.58278    1  -71.6089 -33.5031
53    53  256.00458 165.33361100  21.301138  511.40500    1  -54.4162 -25.6967
54    54  271.00000 170.00000000  60.000000  362.54198    1  -60.4542 -25.9167
56    56  229.00000 112.35964626  25.000000  301.35039    1  -59.0210 -33.6877
57    57  119.99753  15.10747321  54.000000  471.71589    1  -71.7248 -42.7099
58    58  135.70071  20.70070732  72.827280  349.44457    1  -71.0065 -41.0595
59    59  264.00000 174.43120494  23.910081  420.64503    1  -57.0766 -26.0751
60    60  262.52382 173.72329246  25.077236  432.73019    1  -57.0500 -26.0167
62    62  179.34210  80.87832470  86.102021  594.32138    1  -72.6524 -37.8537
63    63  154.27204  63.26968212  83.647330  756.03579    1  -72.7667 -37.6333
64    64  170.36894  82.95671452  76.716261  582.33120    1  -72.9125 -38.0167
65    65  255.29339 141.05130937  44.000000  362.34977    1  -59.6919 -30.0224
68    68  244.00000 126.00000000  47.000000  373.97578    1  -60.7068 -31.8564
70    70  169.65447  81.75782454  60.138823  575.48334    1  -72.6000 -38.7333
71    71  280.00000 209.22244349  60.000000  311.98601    1  -60.0000 -20.0000
74    74  173.06376  91.94939494  86.649798  808.16328    1  -72.9333 -37.1667
75    75   93.88276  -3.88122756 123.993938  122.31361    1  -65.7049 -23.1626
77    77  244.73709 128.25037481  48.750699  368.01469    1  -60.7000 -31.6333
78    78  238.25716 118.42208981  26.120460  317.28934    1  -58.5249 -33.0121
79    79  264.68778 215.00000000  54.000000  469.93021    1  -63.0000 -17.0000
81    81  132.00000  77.00000000  37.000000  770.18289    1  -74.1167 -43.3500
82    82  204.24999  73.75029357  31.762202  275.78719    1  -60.2000 -37.3000
84    84  230.00000 113.03251305  23.367766  283.85559    1  -58.7333 -33.4833
85    85  239.68529 122.46175316  12.326192  327.46175    1  -55.7766 -32.5428
86    86  192.89750  78.09241708  19.000000  252.85173    1  -58.0658 -37.8406
87    87  127.72334  35.72334013  73.511696 1099.73574    1  -71.8167 -38.2167
90    90  225.43089 107.43089205  22.000000  304.29268    1  -58.3902 -34.8034
91    91  134.53429  72.02286008  40.000000  865.02286    1  -73.6167 -43.1167
92    92  225.07390 102.00000000  39.238986  337.55187    1  -60.7313 -34.2004
93    93  255.09615 141.09614673  15.688826  373.75971    1  -56.4500 -30.4300
95    95  168.91143  99.08857071  84.088571  593.54574    1  -73.0167 -36.7333
96    96  241.33689 219.33688825  75.000000  952.96431    1  -59.0000 -13.0000
97    97  267.51799 180.35046950  87.000000  353.46857    1  -63.0700 -20.8700
98    98  262.97274 210.03301311  61.289635  734.77698    1  -63.6667 -17.4500
99    99  217.00000  98.96529301  18.652335  283.29342    1  -57.9995 -35.5728
102  102  229.00000 107.00000000  28.000000  311.07590    1  -59.8228 -34.3834
104  104  225.00000 104.96487882  22.610418  318.55003    1  -59.0000 -34.4000
105  105  259.00000 147.04660936  24.512470  410.87977    1  -57.0944 -29.7149
107  107  244.31221 120.02550008  33.687788  366.17838    1  -59.0000 -31.8333
108  108  208.64289  87.07940941  14.000000  206.82547    1  -57.1347 -37.0029
109  109  248.30467 157.12855496  18.887519  493.23855    1  -54.3167 -25.9000
112  112  259.00000 151.00000000  22.000000  434.28496    1  -56.6444 -29.1753
113  113  227.87889 110.74950291  22.000000  310.87978    1  -58.3934 -34.7014
114  114  188.31179  83.92218970  17.311789  259.70139    1  -57.8431 -38.2656
116  116  224.69761 106.55401173  23.302389  327.10194    1  -58.5911 -34.4191
117  117  222.10785 105.00227249  25.889880  343.91302    1  -58.7179 -34.5725
118  118  200.28610  81.28609587  20.000000  248.04349    1  -58.2529 -37.8511
119  119  254.42257 162.36128278  19.840207  503.72360    1  -55.6030 -27.4438
120  120  249.80225 132.00000000  50.000000  358.77755    1  -61.0000 -31.0000
124  124  231.00000 142.00000000  15.000000  389.98814    1  -51.0936 -31.2872
126  126  235.43596 148.97624749  10.953114  404.58779    1  -50.9919 -29.9444
127  127  234.99430 153.85461324  11.073286  388.21653    1  -51.7181 -29.9433
128  128  233.60352 152.60352054   8.912486  383.80058    1  -51.3247 -29.7000
129  129  244.81880 184.81879611  42.716919 1025.62246    1  -46.4197 -23.8900
131  131  213.06989 159.02007109  60.544541  617.99241    1  -46.6339 -23.5503
133  133  212.30438 154.80780343  67.000000  636.61384    1  -46.8800 -23.1803
137  137  223.21176 165.93543578  70.980998  654.28145    1  -46.9797 -22.7003
22     2  194.00099  73.00099051  26.001083  276.00325    0  -59.1797 -37.3630
310    3  205.99766  62.99766278  20.000000   65.00000    0  -66.6797 -40.7797
410    4  267.99982 119.00012978  90.000314  163.00107    0  -67.0130 -30.1547
66     6  218.00083 127.00051598  16.000000  423.99824    0  -52.6380 -31.4047
8      8  272.99900 256.99786347  80.002135  769.99245    0  -48.2213 -10.5714
910    9  258.99943 245.00000000  20.999083  908.00078    0  -75.9297  -1.0297
1010  10  280.00232 267.00116165  86.000000  651.00936    0  -65.6380   8.3036
1110  11  279.00000 174.00000000  87.000000  465.99622    0  -63.2213 -23.1130
121   12  249.00582 217.00581833  70.999999  704.98944    0  -55.4297 -15.3214
14    14  273.00147 251.00146645  83.000000  809.99861    0  -51.3463 -12.9880
151   15  246.00666 221.00665863  85.001131  906.97968    0  -49.9713 -15.6964
161   16  263.00137 249.00250902  50.000000  835.00547    0  -71.0130  -8.1964
171   17  224.99969  99.99969124  43.000000  335.99883    0  -61.1797 -34.1547
181   18  228.99874 203.99940734  80.999335  669.99256    0  -47.6380 -15.4880
191   19  268.99981 254.99946750  98.000347  827.99056    0  -38.3880  -3.9047
201   20   76.98821  -0.01070989  17.000000  132.00969    0  -67.3463 -54.6964
25    25  229.00100 147.99999952  18.000000  521.00148    0  -53.5963 -25.3630
261   26  264.00251 247.00271798  54.000207  966.99373    0  -55.5130   0.1786
271   27  187.01335  46.01069668  35.998369   53.99662    0  -69.4713 -38.4047
281   28  228.00046 213.99999953  73.000000  815.00304    0  -60.7213 -12.6130
291   29  268.00058 262.00000000  45.000000  940.99818    0  -63.5547  -5.3630
301   30  228.01359 218.01360884  54.000000 1191.84478    0  -73.0547   9.4286
311   31  267.99977 257.99977009  12.001378  956.99770    0  -73.5130  -2.5714
321   32  253.00035 243.00034548  70.000000  897.99648    0  -51.8047  -4.6547
331   33  259.00000 242.99977322  58.000000  746.00023    0  -71.0130 -10.3214
35    35  266.00115 234.00023820 129.998376  343.98683    0  -80.1380  -2.8214
361   36  239.00091 158.00203076   9.999796  490.99858    0  -53.3880 -27.0714
371   37  256.00107 223.00214169  82.000471  710.99743    0  -49.6797 -18.4880
381   38  264.99942 250.99884783  29.998848 1096.99310    0  -70.4297   1.0536
391   39   15.01118 -12.98915222  81.002712  506.99793    0  -75.9713 -12.2797
401   40  259.00048 148.99941053  29.000000  407.99775    0  -57.8047 -29.1130
411   41  271.00000 261.99999933  39.998855  874.99310    0  -62.3047  -4.3214
421   42  245.99772 232.99637349  74.000000 1106.00622    0  -54.6380  -9.0714
431   43  270.00000 254.99884138  37.001159 1035.03518    0  -58.9713   5.6786
441   44  210.99715 171.99887466  77.000001  800.00466    0  -47.0547 -19.8214
451   45  258.99980 247.00000000  67.000000  783.00282    0  -53.5130  -4.5714
461   46  290.00000 265.00000000  85.999424  911.00865    0  -68.5547   7.2203
471   47  278.00101 181.99999886  68.998878  276.00123    0  -61.2213 -23.4464
481   48  262.99508 220.99508159  72.002646  313.03257    0  -36.8463  -9.9047
491   49  268.00000 247.99999990  59.000000  800.00140    0  -67.8880 -10.6130
501   50  248.99900 185.99899706  47.000000  460.00236    0  -52.2213 -22.2797
511   51  263.00095 228.00095374  92.001329  343.99639    0  -39.7630  -8.0714
521   52  266.00199 258.00132718  41.000444  959.00026    0  -65.0130   3.1370
531   53  251.00102 214.00036761  23.000651  262.00170    0  -39.2630 -12.6130
55    55  258.00020 248.00020222  74.999546  910.00354    0  -51.3880  -4.7380
561   56  223.00509 177.00376930  87.000000  680.00092    0  -42.7630 -18.0714
571   57  232.00792 162.00508410  91.000000  439.99713    0  -64.1797 -20.3214
581   58  122.97838  92.97610938 109.995439  423.17753    0  -73.3047 -15.0714
591   59  219.00298 160.00429666  73.998683  707.97064    0  -45.2213 -22.9047
61    61  278.00059 265.99955351  73.000000  994.99690    0  -60.5547   1.3870
621   62  264.99965 251.99965249  68.999652  931.99988    0  -54.5547  -3.0297
631   63  262.00057 252.99885628  31.000000  784.00057    0  -71.3047  -5.6964
641   64  276.00000 188.99909010  43.999678  324.00000    0  -58.9297 -23.7797
67    67  140.99782  16.99759906  42.000450   52.99995    0  -69.7630 -44.2380
69    69   91.02975   5.03139201  43.000502  727.18200    0  -72.5547 -43.3630
701   70  238.99996 150.99995612  22.999681  546.00091    0  -53.9297 -25.7797
73    73  156.99829  31.99828703  24.000743   55.00000    0  -70.3880 -48.0297
741   74  231.00043 215.00021260  75.000213  952.00132    0  -59.7630 -12.7380
76    76  187.00000  58.99890366  25.001097   58.00110    0  -65.6797 -43.5714
771   77  267.99832 252.99831923 105.998772  684.01876    0  -38.5547  -4.1130
781   78  269.99889 131.00022074  82.999779  177.00133    0  -66.3880 -30.1964
80    80  262.00102 254.00102180  41.000000  892.99807    0  -67.9713  -5.3214
811   81  255.00000 142.00000000  36.000000  376.99893    0  -58.1797 -29.7380
83    83  193.00076  91.00030596  94.000000  539.00085    0  -72.3880 -36.2797
841   84  278.99976 263.99975911  50.000000 1121.00142    0  -56.5547  -1.0297
851   85  250.00067 227.00067291  82.000000  917.00517    0  -55.3880 -13.7380
861   86  260.00000 250.99977489  23.000000  824.99751    0  -69.7630  -3.6130
89    89  282.00038 256.00019033  99.000532  413.00270    0  -41.8880  -7.5297
901   90  270.00000 225.99941948  57.998288  982.01583    0  -65.1797 -15.3214
911   91  267.99899 253.99898537  46.000000  491.01211    0  -61.5963   7.4703
921   92  219.00059  87.99889395  39.000000  319.99779    0  -61.3047 -36.3214
94    94  225.99978  86.99977939  72.999470  271.99907    0  -66.1380 -33.5297
951   95  116.00396   4.00263725  30.998909   74.99845    0  -71.5130 -48.0714
961   96  208.00089 134.00089034  13.000000  504.99850    0  -52.0130 -28.4880
971   97  259.99964 235.00031380  74.000666  869.99228    0  -57.2213 -14.6547
981   98  231.00000  79.00000000  49.999780  166.99961    0  -66.0130 -37.1547
101  101  245.99606 236.99707761  29.998848 1009.00190    0  -65.4713   1.5536
103  103  259.99783 246.99885797  54.001024 1039.00717    0  -68.7213  -7.5714
1041 104  244.00153 195.00152628  76.999074  658.99242    0  -49.1797 -21.0297
106  106  263.99796 253.99796462  71.001017 1446.01159    0  -64.2213   6.1786
1071 107  173.99788 103.99765761 173.996402   14.00164    0  -69.5130 -19.6130
1081 108  240.00781 232.00780741  34.000000  791.98642    0  -63.4713   3.1786
111  111  216.99799 105.99696451 108.002055  399.00018    0  -71.5963 -34.3630
1121 112  264.00119 249.00118836  57.000594  916.99807    0  -54.0547   1.1370
1131 113  265.99668 250.99667928  40.000000  687.99853    0  -74.0130  -8.0297
115  115   83.00514  44.00536119 101.999774  432.98950    0  -70.2630 -15.8630
1161 116  238.00000 118.00000000  17.000590  353.99879    0  -57.5547 -33.2797
1171 117  251.00441 219.00441215  91.999012  314.99232    0  -40.7213  -8.3214
1181 118  271.00022 262.00021686  33.000000  883.99764    0  -62.8880  -3.1964
1191 119  262.00000 252.99942668  25.000000  766.99989    0  -70.9297  -5.0297
123  123  276.00021 263.99964610  71.000215  887.00057    0  -61.5130   1.9703
125  125  247.99556 205.99494311  57.999540  274.00241    0  -36.8047  -9.1130
1261 126  249.99882 231.99882490  71.999271  452.98961    0  -67.4297  10.0120
1271 127  278.00000 236.00000000  69.000000  578.00059    0  -56.9297 -16.5714
1281 128  288.00021 198.99989033  65.999786  306.99978    0  -60.7630 -22.2797
130  130  283.00046 259.00091135  91.999846  722.00153    0  -42.1797  -5.7380
132  132  191.01856 177.01912717  68.003215 1108.93325    0  -73.5547  11.0953
136  136  261.00000 246.00102657  59.000000  726.00457    0  -71.2213  -9.6130
```

the expression for the model structure:

```
model <- pres ~ bioclim_10 + I(bioclim_10^2) + bioclim_11 + I(bioclim_11^2) + bioclim_15 + I(bioclim_15^2) + bioclim_16 + I(bioclim_16^2)
```

the following expression for GLM:

```
GLM <- glm(model, family=binomial(link=logit), data=presausTrain)
```

the results will contain a lot of negative values for the projected suitability for the species:

```
projecaoSuitability <- predict(predictors, GLM)

plot(projecaoSuitability, main='Myocastor coypus')
```

[[image: GLM projection[1]]
For example, at the coorddinates point `-41.55306 -12.39342`, the model predicts:

```
pointXY = data.frame(-41.55306, -12.39342)
suitabAtPoint = extract(predictors,pointXY)
predictedSuitabilityAtPoint = predict(GLM, as.data.frame(suitabAtPoint))
-2.167515
```

I think that negative values is occouring because some mistake of mine, as it make non sense and my Random Forest, Maxent and Bioclim returns values ranging from 0 to 1.

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: possibly.. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103645/why-does-a-binomial-glm-give-negative-predictions

Comment: As shown in the link, your predictions are the log odds due to the logit link.  If you want predictions on the data scale you can use `type = "response"` within `predict`.

Comment: Crude mistake, so embarrassing... my bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `type = 'response'` argument in your call of `predict` (the default is `link`). This will give you fitted probabilities rather than their natural logs.

Comment: So embarrassing, crude mistake... my bad. Thank you.

Comment: @user3369932 no need to be embarrassed, your question is likely to help someone else avoid the same mistake.